# I am solving a practice competitive programming question and i am unable to figure what's going wrong

Tags: javascript

Problem Statement:
You’re given containers lined up in a certain order holding certain volumes of milk. The milk in each container is poured into the successive container and this is continued till the last, given a total pours of one less than the number of containers. If the volume of milk poured into a container is greater than available volume it gets spilt. Find the volume of milk collected in the last container and also the volume of milk spilt during the pours.

Input format:
The first line of input consists of an integer t denoting the number of test cases. Each test case consists of three lines. The first line of each test case consists of an integer n denoting the number of containers. The second line consists of n space separated integers each (v) denoting the maximum volume of milk the container at that position can hold. The third line consists of n space separated integers each (i) denoting the initial volume of milk present in the container at that position.

Output Format:
For each test case output the final the volume of milk collected in the last container and also the volume of milk spilt.

This is the code that I've written. I applied the for loop and changed the initial array according to the problem but i am not getting any output

```
for(i=0;i<max_limit.length-2;i++){
    var spilt_milk = 0;

    if(a[i]+a[i+1]>max_limit[i+1]){
        spilt_milk = spilt_milk + a[i]+a[i+1]-max_limit[i+1];
        a[i] = 0;
        a[i+1] = max_limit[i+1];
    }
   else{
       a[i] = 0;
       a[i+1] = a[i]+ a[i+1];
       spilt_milk = spilt_milk;
   } 
return spilt_milk;
}
```

Expected Output should be something like this
4 2

Comment: Can you show the input which you would want to produce that expected output? `max_limit` and `a` look to be the undeclared variables

Comment: max_limit is an array containing the max_values of the container . I showed the code where I performed the working of output. For this output max_limit = [2,3,4] and initial values = [1,2,3].

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58281821/edit), then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Do you need python answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t>0){
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        int c[n]={0}, m[n]={0};
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            cin>>c[i];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            cin>>m[i];
        int wastage=0;
        for(int i=1; i<n; i++){         //calculating amount of milk for 2nd to last container
            m[i]=m[i]+m[i-1];           //milk in current container = milk in current container + milk in previous container
            if(m[i]>c[i]){              //if milk in current container is more than its capacity
                wastage+=m[i]-c[i];     //wastage = total milk in current container - its capacity
                m[i]=c[i];              //new amount will be equal to its capacity
            }
        }
        cout<<m[n-1]<<" "<<wastage<<endl;
        t--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```